# radio button form code and dropdown menu code

Tags: php, javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I have a simple php contact form but cannot get the radio buttons to only choose only 1 option (selection required). 
Also not sure of the script needed for drop down box (this selection is not required)

```
//radio button individual or team required 
if(trim($_POST['individual']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $individual = trim($_POST['individual']);
}

//radio button individual or team required  
if(trim($_POST['team']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $team = trim($_POST['team']);
}


<input type="radio" name="individual" value="individual" id="individual" checked="checked">Individual</label>
<input type="radio" name="team" value="team" id="team" > Team</label>
<label for="shirt"> <strong>T-Shirt size (Optional)</strong></label>
    <br />
      <select name="Shirt Sizes" id="shirt">
                    <option value="small" name="small" id="small">Small</option>
                    <option value="medium" name="medium" id="medium" selected="selected">Medium</option>
                    <option value="large" name="large" id="large">Large</option>
                    <option value="xlarge" name="xlarge" id="xlarge">Extra Large</option>
                    </select>
```

Any help would be great.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to name all your radio buttons the same for your browser to understand they are grouped.

```
<input type="radio" name="team" value="individual" id="individual" checked="checked">Individual</label>
<input type="radio" name="team" value="team" id="team" > Team</label>
```

When it is posted, the `value` is sent under the variable name of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons must have the same name if you want the browser to enforce the selection of only one of them

```
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="individual" id="individual" checked="checked">Individual</label>
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="team" id="team" > Team</label>
```

Then in PHP, you can check which was selected with:

```
if(isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    if($_POST['quantity'] == 'individual') {
        // individual
    } elseif($_POST['quantity'] == 'team') {
        // team
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if this was just a product of copying and pasting, but you are missing opening label tags before both of your radio buttons.

**Edit:** This another minor thing not related to your question, but unless you have a specific need for it, your `<option>`s don't need to have a name attribute. The value will do (and they don't need an id either unless you need an easy way to access them individually with JS).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the radio buttons in the same group the same "name" attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="individual" id="individual" checked="checked">Individual</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="team" id="team" > Team</label>
```

That way when you click on one it will unselect the other one.

Comment: Thanks!Can anyone help out with the php code I need to use for the dropdown menu to work?